# How to exclude/filter a tag from get_the_tag_list()

Tags: filters, tags, exclude

Does anyone know how to exclude/filter a tag from the HTML string generated by get_the_tag_list()?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tag_list

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function mytheme_filter_tags( $term_links ) {
    $result = array();
    $exclude_tags = array( 'some tag', 'another tag', 'third tag' );
    foreach ( $term_links as $link ) {
        foreach ( $exclude_tags as $tag ) {
            if ( stripos( $link, $tag ) !== false ) continue 2;
        }
        $result[] = $link;
    }
    return $result;
}
add_filter( "term_links-post_tag", 'mytheme_filter_tags', 100, 1 );

// do loop stuff
echo get_the_tag_list('<p>Tags: ',', ','</p>');
// end loop stuff

remove_filter( "term_links-post_tag", 'mytheme_filter_tags', 100 );
```

Comment: Thanks very much Eugene. Works perfectly. Just a couple of follow up questions regarding your answer:

1. If I wanted to match the tag exactly (but case insensitive) which php string comparison function is best to use in this situation?

2. Why have you set the priority of the filters to 100?

Comment: #1 if I understand you correctly, you need `strcasecmp` function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php

Comment: #2 I pursued two following goals:


- to execute my filter function after anyone else filter


- and to remove exactly my function from filters list

Answer (score 1):

This is a snippet from one of my blogs:

```
function get_filtered_tags($post_id) {
    // the slugs to be INCLUDED in the term list:
    $primary_tags = array( 'books', 'travel', ... ); 

    $post_tags = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, 'post_tag');

    if( ! empty( $post_tags ) ) {
        if( ! is_wp_error( $post_tags )) {
            $tag_end = __( ', ', 'twentytwelve' );
            foreach ( $post_tags as $term ) {
                $term_slug = $term->slug;
                if ( in_array( $term_slug, $primary_tags) ) {
                    if ( isset( $tag_list ) ) {
                        $tag_list .= $tag_end;
                    }
                    $tag_list .= '<a href="' . get_term_link($term_slug, 'post_tag') . 
                        '">' . $term->name . '</a>'; 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $tag_list;
}
```

If you want to exclude `$primary_tags` do the following instead:

```
if ( ! in_array( $term_slug, $primary_tags) ) {
    ... 
}
```

I.e. add a `!` before `in_array( ... )`.

Answer (score -1):

`get_the_tag_list` calls `get_the_term_list` which then calls `get_the_terms` that has a filter named `get_the_terms` so you can use that filter to exclude your tags:

```
//add filter
add_filter( 'get_the_terms', 'exclude_terms_48735', 10, 1 );
//function to do filtering
function exclude_terms_48735( $terms ) {
    //list the unwanted terms ids
    $blacklist_terms = array( 1,2,3);
    // loop through the terms
    foreach( $terms as $k => $term ) {
        //only remove term if it's ID is in the array.
        if(in_array( $term->term_id, $blacklist_terms, true )) 
            unset( $terms[$k] );
    }
    return $terms;
}
```

Comment: If you add hook on filter `'get_the_terms'`, it will have effect on different other functions, which use `get_the_terms` internally. By doing it you exclude tags "globally".

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Bainternet. I went with Eugene's answer because I only wanted to change the output of get_the_tag_list in this case.